# WYSIWYG: Model based ( Quill, Trix ) vs Classic HTML ( CKEditor4, Froala ); what's the advantage of the first?

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, contenteditable, quill

in these dark days I'm struggling trying to find out which is the best choice for me; I'm developing a Medium-like editor. At the moment I'm using medium-editor ( https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor ) to handle the text input and formatting, but the HTML it generates is.. awful. 
So, search search search, and wow, they invented something like Quill that gives you a JSON model of the HTML tree. 
Wow, incredible, but.. what are the pros?

I can see a couple of things that are surely good with this approach:

1. you don't rely on browsers inconsistent `contenteditableà
2. it is a more elegant solution
3. ?

After spending some time using Quill I surely can say that, yes, the JSON structure is fantastic but the development **isn't easy at all**. 
And for the HTML generated: can totally say that CKEditor4 generates really great HTML.

So here it is my question, because I'm surely missing something here: what are the advantages of using something like Quill than the old and classical HTML editor like CKEditor4 ( that works with `contenteditable` too )?

Comment: You can also use CKEditor 5 which has a custom data model but, by default, produces an HTML. And it provides the [balloon editor](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/examples/builds/balloon-editor.html) :). Regarding relying on `contentEditable` – all web-based RTEs like Quill, CKEditor 5, etc. rely on `contentEditable`. Read more in https://medium.com/content-uneditable/contenteditable-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-261a38555e9c why.

I'll write a longer answer later on... if the community won't close your question ;)